# How to display image from firebase storage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to upload an image to firebase storage and retrieve the image from firebase storage. But, the "retrieve" case is not working:

```
// image upload
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/'+file.name);
storageRef.put(file);
function error(err) {
    console.log("error",err);
} 

// retrieve image from firebase storage
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var spaceRef = storageRef.child('profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/'+file.name);
storageRef.child('profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/'+file.name).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    console.log("bsbdsbsdbd");
    var test = url;
    alert("hfdghjghj",url);
}).catch(function(error) { });
```

Comment: Can you see it uploaded in the console?

Comment: yes ,its shown in the console@dpix

Comment: try to print out any errors. also if you run this code the .put() method will execute async. so when you try to download the file it might not be available yet

Comment: thanks @ChristopherRivera , i got an error from firebase .it is error r {code: "storage/object-not-found", message: "Firebase Storage: Object 'profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/download (3).jpg' does not exist.", serverResponse: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"↵  }↵}", name: "FirebaseError"}

Comment: As @ChristopherRivera mentioned, are you waiting for the file to finish uploading before trying to retrieve it? The error would suggest it does not exist in firebase yet.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress describes how to add a handler to determine when the upload has completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with seeing your error message the idea is todo

```
StorageRef.put(file, function(){
  // Now do the download
})
```

Or have a handler that waits till the file is uploaded

Comment: thank you @Christopher , i created a handler that wait for file upload and got download url

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this...

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(filePath);

function uploadImage(event){
  var file = event.target.files[0];

  return storageRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
    // put the file now do something...
    var fullPath = snapshot.metadata.fullPath;
    console.log(fullPath);
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error uploading "+error);
  });
}

function retrieveImage(imageUri, imgElement){
  if (imageUri.startsWith('gs://')) {
    storageRef.refFromURL(imageUri).getMetadata().then(function(metadata) {
      imgElement.src = metadata.downloadURLs[0];
      console.log("URL is "+metadata.downloadURLs[0]);
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log("error downloading "+error);
    });
  }
}
```

This will use Promise's to carry out actions once the file has been uploaded successfully.

It will also log to the console when error's occur.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePicturesOfAbmin/original/')

storageRef.listAll().then(res => {
    //for folders
    res.perfixes.forEach(folder => {
        console.log(folder);
    });
    // for files NAME and URL
    res.items.forEach(item => {
        // console.log( item.name ); 
        item.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            console.log(url);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi @Khalid Butt, could you edit your answer and put a brief explanation of what is causing the issue in the OP, as well as what is the actual fix in your answer? That will help future visitors.